# Memory allocation when replacing column of Matrix

Tags: r

I am currently having an issue with memory usage in a script I am writing. The code where the issue is:

```
for (i in 1:44){
    selectToAnd <- testList[,2]==i
    toAnd <- resultsMatrix[,selectToAnd, drop = FALSE]
    if(ncol(toAnd)==1){
        compiledMatrix[,i] <- toAnd
    }
    else{
        compiledMatrix[,i] <- rowSums(toAnd)==ncol(toAnd)
    }
}
```

For context, `compiledMatrix` and `resultsMatrix` are both huge logical matrices, `compiledMatrix` is `44` cols by `~3` million rows and `resultsMatrix` is `~100` cols by `~3` million rows. I couldn't really put together a reproducible example here because my issue is due to the sizes of the objects in question.

When I run this, it tells me `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 556.4 Mb`. As far as I have been able to discern, the issue is here:

```
if(ncol(toAnd)==1){
    compiledMatrix[,i] <- toAnd
}
else{
    compiledMatrix[,i] <- rowSums(toAnd)==ncol(toAnd)
}
```

I *think* what may be happening is that when I change a row of `compiledMatrix`, `R` allocates memory for a new version of the matrix. One of the reasons I think this is that `compiledMatrix` is about `550 Mb` from when I checked using `object.size()`. I declared a logical matrix of all `TRUE` as `compiledMatrix` before the loop to avoid creating it by pasting columns together. Is it reasonable that this is what is happening? If so, is there a way to prevent `R` from creating a new matrix every time I want to modify it?

Comment: The data.table objects do assignments internally. (Do an SO of google search on that spelling.) You can also do c++ coding with the Rcpp based packages. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r+rcpp?sort=votes&pageSize=50  Most R functions do make copies upon reassignment of values.

Comment: @42 Thanks, good to know. I guess I am used to internal assignments- my first programming class hammered it into me that it is important to preallocate space for objects so as not to change them later :).

Comment: Well, pre-allocation can be useful in R to improve efficiency but to use compiled language logic regarding mutable objects, you probably want to use Rcpp.